# How to update the list inside a multiple for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I want to make a grid-like structure and willing to check that the geographical point lie in the cell or not?

I have Tuple of coordinates as a tuple shown below, I have other coordinates as a list of the list which also contains some coordinate, a different number of coordinate in each sublist. I want the check each coordinate of the sublist inside coordinates with the geographical coordinate in the Tuple. As a result, I want a list of size of Tuple for each sublist of coordinate with value 1 or 0(based on the given condition). If coordinates of the sublist of a coordinate lie in the range of coordinate of data1 write 1 else 0.

If I pick a geographical point (6.8, 51.35) from sublist of coordinate, I will check it each geographical coordinates of Tuple, like a=(x,y) modify it to (z=x+0.49, p=y+0.49), 0.49 because the cell gap is 0.05, then compare the value (6.8, 51.35) with a range of (a,b) & (z,p), replace the value (x,y) with 1 else 0.

```
Tuple = ((6.8, 51.35), (6.85, 51.4), (6.9, 51.45), (6.95, 51.5), (7.0, 51.55), (7.05, 51.6), (7.1, 51.65), (7.15, 51.7), (7.2, 51.75), (7.25, 51.8), (7.3, 51.85), (7.35, 51.9), (7.4, 51.95), (7.45, 52.0), (7.5, 52.05), (7.55, 52.1), (7.6, 52.15), (7.65, 52.2), (7.7, 52.25), (7.75, 52.3), (7.8, 52.35), (7.85, 52.4), (7.9, 52.45), (7.95, 52.5), (8.0, 52.55), (8.05, 52.6), (8.1, 52.65), (8.15, 52.7), (8.2, 52.75), (8.25, 52.8), (8.3, 52.85), (8.35, 52.9), (8.4, 52.95), (8.45, 53.0), (8.5, 53.05), (8.55, 53.1), (8.6, 53.15), (8.65, 53.2), (8.7, 53.25), (8.75, 53.3), (8.8, 53.35), (8.85, 53.4), (8.9, 53.45), (8.95, 53.5), (9.0, 53.55), (9.05, 53.6), (9.1, 53.65), (9.15, 53.7), (9.2, 53.75), (9.25, 53.8), (9.3, 53.85), (9.35, 53.9), (9.4, 53.95), (9.45, 54.0), (9.5, 54.05), (9.55, 54.1), (9.6, 54.15), (9.65, 54.2), (9.7, 54.25), (9.75, 54.3), (9.8, 54.35), (9.85, 54.4), (9.9, 54.45))

coordinate = [[('9.72', '52.33071'), ('9.72005', '52.3306')],[('9.7909166', '52.353843'), ('9.7907', '52.35399'), ('9.7904', '52.35417'), ('9.7897', '52.35454'), ('9.7891696', '52.354815')]]
```

The code I wrote is

```
for i in range(0,2):
    list=[]
    point=cordinate[i]
    y=len(cordinate[i])
    print(y)
    for j in range(0,y):
       l=float(point[j][0])
       m=float(point[j][1])
       #list=[]
       for k in range(0,len(Tuple)):
           x=Tuple[k][0]
           y=Tuple[k][1]
           gap = 0.049
           if (x < l < x + gap) and (y < m < y + gap):
               value = 1
           else:
               value = 0
           list.append(value)
   print(list)
```

Current Output:

```
2
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Expected output There should list of size 63, which contains 0 or 1:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Your description includes `Data1` and `Data2` but this isn't in your example code. Your code also calls `cordinate` which isn't shown. IT's also not clear what z and p re for. Can you simplify your example a bit to only have the bit you are stuck with?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
As the posting guidelines tell you, make it easy for other to help you.  Single-letter variable names and lack of a varied example make this hard to follow.

Comment: Do you mean all coordinates within a sublist of Data2 should be within range of a coordinate of Data1?

Comment: @match please have a look , I updated the question

Comment: @prune agree, I updated the issue, I hope now I can get some help

Comment: @Jay, yes because each point of the sublist will be compared with data1

Comment: Your posted code still does not run.  It is still hard to read.  Your example is still all zeros.  Do you *really* require 63 input points to illustrate your problem???  **MCVE** is expected.

Comment: @prune I am sorry, Please check it again, I checked the same variable and code is running in my system.

Comment: Nope.  `cordinate` is undefined (misspelled).  With that repaired, I still face the other problems.

Comment: GAUTAM: The code in your latest update won't run and doesn't produce what you claim is the current output even if the code problem is fixed.

Comment: You get `63 * len(coordinates)` zeros because that's what you programmed: you report on each cell for each point.  *Why* do you expect only 63 zeroes?  Your example doesn't include any 1's, so we're unclear on how this is supposed to work.  Is the entry supposed to be `1` if any one point falls within that cell?

Comment: @Prune, this is a dummy data, I have a larger version of data which has 1 also, I got a solution if I could add the list in each iteration inside  for k in range(0,len(Tuple)): then the I will get the same number of zero but I am able do it in loop, example [0,0,0,1] + [0,0,0,0]= [0,0,0,0]

Comment: I would love to solve your problem, but I need to know what that problem is.  I need you to specify the problem clearly; you may need to get a friend to help, one who understands English grammar and pronoun references a little better than you (you're *almost* there).  Also, it would help if you would address each of my concerns, instead of only the most immediate one.  When I use a specific reference, please answer using that reference, rather than shifting from problem specification to a detached code snippet.

Comment: @Prune okay, thank you, replying to your last comment, 63 * len(coordinates). I am using len(coordinates[i]) because I wanted to compare all geographical point inside the coordinates[0], there are 2 points, in 2nd iteration 5 points. That's why I am getting the output as 63 * len(coordinates). Instead of appending 63 value + 63 value in 1st iteration, can we do a summation of 63 value + 63 values os that I get only 63 values, is it possible?

Comment: We're still getting buried in details.  Yes, it's straightforward to add two lists of the same length.  This is covered in many places on line.  Does that handle your problem?  I'm still not sure what you're trying to do.  Summing the two lists could result in a higher number showing up, which is outside the problem you describe and beyond your coding attempt.  I'll wait for the problem specification and MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems.  The first two are related: `Vic` pointed out that your "else" clause is executed whether or not the inner `if` is `True`.  To simplify that check, upgrade your gap-checking code with

```
gap = 0.049
if (x < l < x + gap) and \
   (y < m < y + gap):
    value = 1
else:
    value = 0

list.append(value)
```

This also repairs your second problem: in "found" cases, you would append `value` twice: once inside the `if`, and once after.

Also, note that you can reduce that check to one long item:

```
list.append(int((x < l < x + gap) and (y < m < y + gap)))
```

---

Finally, you have a problem-problem in that your data will not produce any `1` values by design.  You have defined a diagonal series of cells.  The first has diagonal corners of (6.8, 51.35) and (6.849, 51.399); the next picks up at the second corner and continues along the diagonal of your grid.

The points in `coordinate` do not fall into any of those cells.  For instance, the first point is

```
(9.72, 52.33071)
```

The grid (`Tuple`) points with the containing `x` coordinates are

```
(9.7, 54.25), (9.75, 54.3)
```

But the required `y` coordinates are nearly two units (40 steps) above that point.  Thus, there is no matching cell for that point.  The other coordinate points have the same problem.  You simply do not have any data point that fits the criteria, so your output list will be all zeroes.

It appears that either your data or your problem description is faulty.

Comment: I have many points in coordinates, for k in range(0,len(Tuple)):                                     
             x=Tuple[k][0]
            y=Tuple[k][1]
            gap=0.05
            list.append(int((x < l < x + gap) and (y < m < y + gap)))
       print(list)        I am getting output as list of 0, in increasing number 0 as per the number of geographical points in sublist of cordiantes, 126 for 2 points, 315 times 0 for 5 points, I am confused with the position of list.

Comment: I'm unclear about your statement "I have many points in coordinates".  None of those points are within the diagonal cells you define, as I described in my answer.

Comment: One final time: please edit your question to serve as a MCVE.  Don't post code in comments.  Post clarifications under your question, not under an answer.

Comment: I have updated the code and output based on your suggestion, the number of 0 in output depends on the number of points in coridantes[i]...for 2, its 126 for 5 its 315. is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Gautam I agree with the comments above about an MCVE submission. One place you may want to look at based on the code you posted is your 4-parameter if statement:

```
    if l>x and l<z:
      if m>y and m<p:
        value=1
    else : value = 0
```

You are probably getting the undesired output from this code because your else statement executes every iteration.

Comment: Based on your latest submission you expect output that is either 1 or 0. But the code of yours I posted above is always leading you to a value of 0. When l>x and l<z never occurs because you are assigning l and then arbitratily adding 0.49 + x to z. So the value of l is never inbetween x and z. You need to review the logic in your code that led you to the example of your code I posted.

Comment: True, I have many points in coordinates, I can't post all here, I am worried about the output a list, for each sublist of coordinates there must be only one list of size Tuple